# Python: Other options versus using '__contains__`? I was told I should not use it

Tags: python, contains

I have a working file [below], but I would like to know if there is a better solution to the first three lines.

I have several files in a folder, and a script that processes them based on a particular and conserved `<string>` in each file's name. However, I was told I should not use `__contains__` (I am not a CS major, and don't fully understand why). Is there a better option? I could not find any other concise solution.

Thanks.

```
files = os.listdir (work_folder)
for i in files:
    if i.__contains__('FOO'):
        for i in range (number_of_files):
            old_file = 'C:/path/to/file'
            with open(merged_file, 'a+') as outfile:
                with open(old_file) as infile:
                    for line in infile:
                        outfile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally in Python, double-underscore methods should not be called directly; you should use the global functions or operators that correspond to them. In this case, you would do `if 'FOO' in i`.

Comment: I see. So would there be an "appropriate," or even necessary, situation where one would use the double-underscored method, since they all have global functions?

Answer (score 5):

It would be more usual to write

```
if 'FOO' in i:
```

instead of

```
if i.__contains__('FOO'):
```

However, I would go one further than that and suggest your use case is more suited to `glob`

```
import glob
foo_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(work_folder, '*FOO*'))
```

Answer (score 2):

As Daniel Roseman explains, the double-underscore methods aren't there to be called by you, they're there to be called by the Python interpreter or standard library.

So, that's the main reason you shouldn't call them: It's not idiomatic, so it will confuse readers.

---

But all you know is that there must be *some* operation that you *are* intended to use, which Python will implement by calling the `__contains__` method. You have no idea what that operation is. How do you find it?

Well, you could just go to Stack Overflow, and someone helpful like Daniel Roseman will tell you, of course. But you can also search for `__contains__` in the Python documentation. What you'll find is [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__):

> `object.__contains__(self, item)`
>
> > Called to implement membership test operators. Should return `true` if
> >     *item* is `in` *self*, `false` otherwise.

So, `self.__contains__(item)` is there for Python to implement `item in self`.

And now you know what to write: `'FOO' in i`.

---

And if you read on in those linked docs, you'll see that it isn't actually quite true that `i.__contains__('FOO')` does the same thing as `'FOO' in i`. That's true for the most common cases (including where `i` is a string, as it is here), but if `i` doesn't have a `__contains__` method, but is an iterable, or an old-style sequence, `in` will use those instead.

So, that's another reason not to directly call `__contains__`. If you later add some abstraction on top of strings, maybe a virtual iterable of grapheme clusters or something, it may not implement `__contains__`, but `in` will still work.